# Python: search and replace - string delineation issue

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, search

Trying to find and replace a list of strings (separated by new lines) such as

```
aba
abanga
abaptiston
abarelix
```

With a list like

```
aba
aca
ada
```

Such that, if an item in the second list appears in the first it should be deleted.

I have code that half works

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

with open("words.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

str = ''.join(str(e) for e in content)  #list may include numbers

delet = {"aba":"", "aca":"", "ada":"",}
txt = replace_all(str, delet)

f = open("deltedwords.txt","w") 
f.write(txt)
```

Unfortunately this will catch false positives of partial strings so the end result will be

```
nga
ptiston
relix
```

Trying to add whitespace or additional characters before the words being searched doesn't work as it tends to produce only false negatives.

Comment: Can you add the expected output?

Comment: @C.B. The expected output would be the exact same as the first list, only with "aba" deleted (i.e. the first entry)

Comment: Will you always be completely deleting lines, or do you also want to do actual replacement? Ex. "`abarelix` should become `QQQQ`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply filter, but I would argue that there is no need for a dictionary if you are simply deleting entries.

If order doesn't matter, use a `set`:

```
>>> content = set(['aba', 'abanga', 'abaptiston', 'abarelix'])
>>> unwanted_words = set(['aba', 'aca', 'ada'])
>>> content.difference(unwanted_words)
set(['abanga', 'abarelix', 'abaptiston'])
```

If it does, just use a list comprehension

```
>>> content = ['aba', 'abanga', 'abaptiston', 'abarelix']
>>> unwanted_words = ['aba', 'aca', 'ada']
>>> [word for word in content if word not in unwanted_words]
['abanga', 'abaptiston', 'abarelix']
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using:

```
content_without_keywords = filter(lambda x: x.strip() not in delet.keys(), content)
txt = ''.join(str(e) for e in content_without_keywords)
```

to remove only exactly matched lines.

Comment: The idea of my answer is basically same as @C.B.'s second code, FYI.

Comment: Of course, my answer is just a direct answer to your exact code and please organize the code after you made it correct. (For example, `delet` doesn't need to be a dict )